# Why is padding of action buttons ignored in the device?

Tags: android

I'm using the following standard way to reduce spacing between action buttons:

(/res/values/styles.xml)

```
<style name="ActionButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton">
  <item name="android:minWidth">2dp</item>
  <item name="android:paddingLeft">2dp</item>
  <item name="android:paddingRight">2dp</item>
</style>
```

Whatever padding values I use (with either text or icon action buttons), including zero, are totally ignored in the Android device (spacing between action buttons is always the same) while they are applied perfectly in the Android emulator using a virtual device created on the exact specifications of the Android device (size and Android version (API 17)).

Comment: What is the reason this question received a negative rating?
Can the person who did this provide at least a comment?

Answer (score 0):

Remove your xml file button padding attribute and set style